# How can I resume movie download in BitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

I was downloading a movie using BitTorrent and i paused it after reaching 58%. But I can't resume it now. It's showing "connecting to peers" for over an hour. What should I do?? Should I cancel and restart?

Comment: Have you tried force recheck? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

So you were downloading a file from a server, but the connection was cut/drive was yanked out/PC crashed, and now you're left with a useless half downloaded file? If you can find a torrent of that exact file, you can resume the download, saving you from wasting your time and bandwidth.

Torrents are also a good way to check for file corruption, especially if the file doesn't come with a hash, since torrents themselves have hashes of the file.
Note that with certain browsers that create a .part file (like Firefox), the .part file is the half-downloaded file, not the one with the normal filename. You'll need to delete the regular file and remove the .part extension from the partially downloaded file for BitTorrent to resume downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the torrent from bittorent client and **Uncheck the delete source file option** Open the torrent file or magnet link (The same you opened before) and choose the same download location. It will resume automatically.